# Android .jar library within .jar library - Nested dependencies

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I recently asked a very similar question, but was unsure how to phrase it. Having received some feedback and researched some of the potential solutions, I'm now asking again with what I believe to be a better explanation of the issue.

My Android App uses my Library (parentLib), this library is built referencing methods from another library (childLib). Therefore, the App itself uses parentLib (A .jar library), which in turn uses childLib (Another .jar library).

The problem here is that when the app attempts to use anything that involves the nested library (childLib), it receives a NoClassDefFoundError, which crashes the App. I believe that this issue is due to the App being unable to resolve the nested dependency.

I can't really use Android library projects, as I need the source code to be as obfuscated and difficult to understand as possible. I have also tried creating these libraries using Android Studio, only to sadly receive no better outcome.

My options (I think) are:

**Combine the Libraries**

I could potentially combine childLib and parentLib into a single .jar library, seperating them out into different packages. This would be difficult though, as in practise there are around 6 nested libraries for my intended App.

**Insist the Client use multiple libraries**

Instead of saying to the client, "Here's one simple library (parentLib) for you to use", I could instead say, "Here's 7 different libraries for you to import (parentLib, childLib, etc.), otherwise nothing will work". Not exactly professional!

**Other Options**

I would welcome any other suggestions anybody has!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, that is not a real solution...are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? Eclipse has a lot compilation problems when you try to include nested libraries. With Android Studio and gradle, I am pretty sure that you won't have any issues about this subject. In an other hand. My suggestion is not combine parentLib and childLib in only one project...my suggestion is to combine your android project with parentlib in the same project. From the main project make a simple reference to childLib.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot combine the app and the libraries, as the end product here is a library which will when be distributed to clients who then develop an app themselves that uses the libraries functionality.

As for your suggestion on Android Studio, I did attempt it, but didn't find it to have any different outcome than Eclipse (Which I'm using currently). Do you think there is a way of having Studio produce a .jar library that references a sub-.jar library? I know it works with libraries in a very different way...?

Comment: these kind of dependencies problems could dissapear. That is the reason that I think that the way to manage the dependencies with graddle and maven is more flexible.

Comment: Interesting! When you did this, were your libraries still in .jar files or did they use Android Studio's aar system?

Comment: _Combining the Libraries_ - This seems like a good option, and should be very easy to do with a simple script. I'm not sure why you claim that it would be difficult (?)

Comment: The sub-libraries in question are all very complicated, very separate, and are all both made and supported by different entities. So getting them fixed when an issue develops becomes complicated if I'm having to give the combined libraries to everybody

Comment: Combining the libraries to me sounds like a bad idea. First of all, you'll create a larger library than you'll probably need, thus waste in resources. Plus such a tight coupling is a bad software engineering practice. NoClassDefFoundError exception occures when `The searched-for class definition **existed** when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.` Could you tell us how you import these libraries to your project? Are they packaged into Jars? Do you check them on Eclipse's Import and Export tab?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I, too, am facing a similar problem.

Comment: @Silmarilos It was a while ago, but I believe the solution was to move to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by moving to Android Studio (where such issues are not present).

Answer (score 0):

The **NoClassDefFoundError** means that the the class was present during compilation, but not available in the classpath when trying to execute it.

So, you need to tell gradle to compile those libraries and package them inside the apk.

Copy all the library jars you need to the **libs** folder in the root of you project. Then, edit the gradle.build file and add the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

This will cause all the required libraries to be added to your apk. This way, the classes you need will be present in the classpath when you execute the code that needs them.